# how effectively i can use ui automation recorded test cases for other releases of the application

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, sahi

I've web application, I want recorded test cases and play back that cases.

1st release of the application, I've login module which has user name and password and recorded 500 test cases for entire application. Among 500 test cases 200 test cases are using logging by username and password.

2nd release of the application, I've login module which has only username, so I want use previous recorded test cases by modifications not like go to all the test cases change the password field. Here I'm having some requirements for the testing framework

- Can I get what are test cases will effect by changing field like in above example?
- Is there any way to update in simple, not going like in all the files and changing

I've used different UI Automation testing tools and record & Play back options are very nice, but I could not find the way I want in the UI Automation test framework.

Is there any Framework available which does the job for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of why you never should record a selenium test case. Whenever you want to update something like login you have to change them all.

What you should do is create a test harness/framework for your application.

1.Start with creating a class for each webpage with 1 function for each element you want to be able to reach.

```
public By username(){
   return By.cssSelector("input[id$='username']");   }
```

2.Create helper classes where you create sequences which you use often.

```
public void login(String username, String password){

      items.username().sendkeys(username);
      items.password().sendkeys(password);
```

}

3.In your common test setup add your login function

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() {
   helper.login("user","password");
```

}

This give you the opportunity to programmaticly create your test cases. So for example if you want to use the same test cases for a different login module where password element is not present it could be changed like this.

```
items.username().sendkeys(username);    
if(isElementPresent(items.password())
    items.password().sendkeys(password);
```

The function "isElementPresent" could look like this

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By locator){
    try {
      driver.findElement(locator);
      logger.trace( "Element " + stripBy(locator) + " found");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      logger.trace( "Element " + stripBy(locator) + " not found");
      return false;
    }
   return true;
  }
```